# Dynamically add new row to table using button click in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a dynamic table using php.Now I want to add this functionality.[image]

When we click the submit button, It should automatically add data to the database and create new row and previous row should be disabled that it can't be edited.How to do this ?

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "header.php";
?>
<body>
<div class="text-center">
<h1>PAYMENT PAGE</h1>
</div>
<hr>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th class="text-center">
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            User ID
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            NIC
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Amount
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Date
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='uid'  placeholder='User ID' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='uname' placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='nic' placeholder='NIC' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='amount' placeholder='Amount' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="date" name='dt' placeholder='Date' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" >SUBMIT</button>
</div>


</body>
</html> 


     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input type='text' name='uid"+i+"'  placeholder='User ID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='uname"+i+"' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='nic"+i+"' placeholder='NIC' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='amount"+i+"' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='date' name='dt"+i+"' placeholder='Date' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simply `disable` the all previous `row` input with `$('tr').find('input').prop('disabled',true)` before new row append .

[**Jquery Documentation of prop()**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNqpbfgZzUAhVMqI8KHZ0cC78QFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fprop%2F&usg=AFQjCNGNNwd6Fkhy4Wn5nWMwXlkmGtIZGw&sig2=IPZ89TX3huBFQGKvSvMdqA)

**Updated** jquery version `3.2.1`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
  $('tr').find('input').prop('disabled',true)
    $('#addr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td><input type='text' name='uid" + i + "'  placeholder='User ID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='uname" + i + "' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='nic" + i + "' placeholder='NIC' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='amount" + i + "' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='date' name='dt" + i + "' placeholder='Date' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<div class="text-center">
  <h1>PAYMENT PAGE</h1>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">
              #
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              User ID
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              NIC
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Amount
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Date
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>
              1
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name='uid' placeholder='User ID' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name='uname' placeholder='Name' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name='nic' placeholder='NIC' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name='amount' placeholder='Amount' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="date" name='dt' placeholder='Date' class="form-control" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both of answers but none of them work.my j query version 3.2.1 and browser is chrome.

Comment: @Manusha see my updated answer.`jquery v 3.2.1` is not problem

Comment: I appreciate your help.But stiil the same.No change.I cant understand why.

Comment: I found the problem.
$('tr').find('input').prop('disabled',true);
semi colon is missing in this statement. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('#addr'+(i-1)).find('input').attr('disabled',true);` to your logic

**Demo** : https://jsfiddle.net/kw4koyvk/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+(i-1)).find('input').attr('disabled',true);
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input type='text' name='uid"+i+"'  placeholder='User ID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='uname"+i+"' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='nic"+i+"' placeholder='NIC' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='amount"+i+"' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='date' name='dt"+i+"' placeholder='Date' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
});
```

Comment: how do you submit this to the database? I tried:

$.post("add_test2.php", { uid : uid+i },function(response){
             console.log(response);

but it never gets called.